# when i store a number having more than 23 digit in SQllite number format is change

Tags: android-sqlite

Table create query is:

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String table_track = "create table tracker_list(tracker_id String)";

        db.execSQL(table_track);
        }
```

Inserting no is :`9114901159818188003856`
But when we fetch data from sqllite it returns converted number :`9.1149E+19`
But I want same number that is inserted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: type string is not recognizable by Sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite is not using `string` as datatype.
Using `text` or `nvarchar` should fix the problem in this case.
These are datatypes that Sqlite accepts:

```
CREATE TABLE ex2(
  a VARCHAR(10),
  b NVARCHAR(15),
  c TEXT,
  d INTEGER,
  e FLOAT,
  f BOOLEAN,
  g CLOB,
  h BLOB,
  i TIMESTAMP,
  j NUMERIC(10,5)
  k VARYING CHARACTER (24),
  l NATIONAL VARYING CHARACTER(16)
);
```

For more information see [Datatypes In SQLite Version 2](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html).

Comment: then how we can insert above 25 digit number in SQLlite. But i am using above create table method and it works fine.

Comment: Using `text` datatype? Or `nvarchar`?

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve the problem, please up vote it ( [like this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/upvote-thank-you.png)) and select it as answer as you can see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: Rather than only posting a link (which may go stale), try to *summarize* at least the most important information. (You can use quotes from that site.)

Comment: Done @Jongware thanks for pointing me to the right direction.